# pandas series to_json memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My production service's memory was constantly increasing, and I think the root cause is the pandas.Series.to_json.

```py
import pandas as pd
import gc
for i in range(0,10):
    series = pd.Series([0.008, 0.002])
    json_string = series.to_json(orient="records")
    _ = gc.collect()
    print("gc_count={}".format(len(gc.get_objects())))
```

output:

```
gc_count=46619
gc_count=46619
gc_count=46620
gc_count=46621
gc_count=46622
gc_count=46623
gc_count=46624
gc_count=46625
gc_count=46626
gc_count=46627
```

What's interesting is that the first and the second call always has the same GC count, and then it starts increasing by one in each iteration.

Has anyone faced this before? Are there ways to avoid the memory leak?

[Python versions tried: 3.8 and 3.9]

Update: This seems to be related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24889 and using to_dict and converting it using json seems to be a workaround.

Comment: this may be worth raising on the pandas github: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed in the latest version of pandas. The bug is there in pandas 1.1.3, and can be reproduced consistently.

Possible solutions

1. Upgrade to the latest version of Pandas.
2. If you have to use older version of Pandas, we can have a workaround like the following:

Instead of

```
series.to_json(orient="records")
```

We can do

```
str(list(series.to_dict().values()))
```